# Saving PostGIS raster as netCDF from SQL Error

Tags: raster, postgis, gdal, netcdf

I am trying to save a raster table in PostGIS as a netCDF file.  When doing so, I get the following error:

> rt_raster_to_gdal: Output GDAL driver does not support CreateCopy and/or VirtualIO.

Reading about the GDAL netCDF driver https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/netcdf.html, it says it supports both CreateCopy and VirtualIO.  When I check the formats of GDAL that are supported I get the following:

> netCDF -raster,vector- (rw+vs): Network Common Data Format

Note that when I perform the same query with PNG format, it works fine.  Its driver seems less capable:

> PNG -raster- (rwv): Portable Network Graphics

The query I am trying to execute is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE loid_temp AS
SELECT lo_from_bytea(0, ST_AsGDALRaster(ST_Union(rast),'netCDF'))
as loid FROM netcdf_test_table
```

This problem seems to occur with any format that has (rw+vs) capability, but works fine with any format that has (rwv) capability.  I am using GDAL version 3.0.4.

Any ideas on why this is occuring?